# get all the td elements of tr when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table and when user clicks into a link need to copy the content of that row and populate them into other fields e.g. edit information. How can the row content be populated as an array

```
<table id='mytable' border='1'>
    <thead>
        <th id='ID'>ID</th>
        <th id='Email'>Email</th>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#">1</a></td>
        <td>abc@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#">2</a></td>
        <td>xyz@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#">3</a></td>
        <td>pqr@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

## jsfiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/keJBZ/5/

Comment: Post the JS you've tried.

Comment: please give an example... if the first link is clicked what value should be copied to where

Comment: This question doesn't make sense.  What do you mean "populate them into other fields"?  What "other fields"?  Also, what does the second question mean?  Which array are you talking about?

Comment: Previously I required only the ID to be pulled out. Please check this http://jsfiddle.net/keJBZ/4/..... But now I need to get the whole row information. e.g. If the user clicks ID 1, I need to get 1,abc@gmail.com  which i need to copy to another block which is hidden and once I get these info, I'll populate them and unhide it for editing purpose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why I've answered this one as your question is as vague as it is.

If you want to pull the information from a selected row into an array, here is how you can do it:

http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/keJBZ/6/

```
var array = new Array();

$('#mytable tr').on('click', copyIntoArray);

function copyIntoArray() {
    var self = $(this);
    var tds = self.children('td');
    array.push(tds[0].innerText, tds[1].innerText);
}
```

It would make a lot of sense to build up an object to push onto the array so you could have KVP or something similar to provide some context.

**EDIT**

Here is your fixed version. No need for the array. I also gave your inputs IDs of "email" and "username" for easier selection.

http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/keJBZ/21/

Final code:

```
$('#mytable tr').on('click', setInformation);

function setInformation() {
    $("#edit").show();
    var self = $(this);
    var tds = self.children('td');
    $('#username').val(tds[1].innerText);
    $('#email').val(tds[2].innerText);
}
```

**FINAL EDIT?!?** turns out FireFox doesn't support .innerText, replaced it with the jQuery to retrieve the values.

http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/keJBZ/24/

This:

```
$('#username').val(tds[1].innerText);
$('#email').val(tds[2].innerText);
```

becomes:

```
$('#username').val($(tds[1]).text());
$('#email').val($(tds[2]).text());
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please have a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/keJBZ/20/ . It'll be more clear now. When user clicks the ID the information must be populated in another filed, which user if required can edit and submit.
Thanks

Comment: Did you look at the jsfiddle where it's working (http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/keJBZ/21/)? Did you put it in a `$(document).ready()` wrapper?

Comment: Which browser? I checked it on IE10 and Chrome.

Comment: Oh..ya I think it's a browser compatibility I'm using firefox22

Comment: I'll look into it, I'm just downloading firefox now.

Comment: instead of innerText, innerContent solved but now there's brower compatibility issue :(

Comment: See here: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/keJBZ/24/ this works on IE9\10, FF and Chrome.

Comment: can it be made while clicking into the link only but not the whole row.. :) thanks

Comment: @user1051068 quick and dirty: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/keJBZ/26/. If you gave your links a class it would be much tider.

Comment: yes, this is what I want. jQuery Guru Thanks a lot. you saved my day :)

Answer (score 0):

Give each row an ID, and then in your JavaScript, use getElementById to get the row which is clicked. Then you can also get all the columns of that row using the same function. You can put all the columns in a var and then use that var to populate whatever you want.